# My C# app is asking my users to install .net 4 - target framework in my project is 2.0?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

I set my target framework in my project properties to .net 2.0

A user running windows 7 is still being prompted to install .net 4... why?

Comment: screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/6AdYW.png

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you uncheck .NET Framework 4 as Prerequisite?

Comment: In Visual Studio, go into project properties, then click the "Publish" tab. Then, under Install Mode and Settings click the "Prerequisites..." button. Uncheck .NET 4 from the list.